# Display single most recent post in category on every page of category archive

Tags: wp-query, pagination, featured-post

I am trying to display a single "featured post" in the archive.php template using a custom query. This featured post should be the **most recent post** in that category or tag. I'm using pagination for the rest of the archive page (also a custom query so that pagination is retained), and this **same post** should appear at the top of **all the subsequent pages** (i.e. /page/2/, /page/3/, etc.)

I've got this working on home.php, but archive.php is showing the most recent post from *each page*, not overall.

This is what I'm using in archive.php.

```
global $query_string;
$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )
);

$query1 = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $query1->have_posts() ) {  
    while( $query1->have_posts() ) {  
        $query1->the_post();      
        get_template_part( 'content', 'latest' );
    }
} 

wp_reset_postdata();
```

And here's the working code from home.php:

```
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )
    );

    $query1 = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $query1->have_posts() ) {  
        while( $query1->have_posts() ) {  
            $query1->the_post();      
            get_template_part( 'content', 'latest' );
        }
    } 

    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Hope I've expressed myself clearly. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Archive.php pulls posts by post date, not by category. So, you will have posts from different categories on the same page. Why aren't you using category.php for this?

Comment: @unifiedac your sentence is not true. Please, [see the template hierarchy in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Comment: Good call. I don't know why I forgot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a loop to display the top (static) post and a second loop for the paginated posts:

[header]

[static latest post] loop 1

[paginated content] loop 2

[footer]

For loop 1 you may need to clearly identify the category in your custom loop.

```
$my_cat = get_query_var('cat');
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'cat'            => $my_cat,
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'post_not_in'    => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )
);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using `get_template_part` to pull the first loop into the archive template, which has the main paginated loop. Your answer is also along the right lines, in that I need to tell the first custom query to get posts in the current category, but I accepted @cybnet's answer because he was first :)

Comment: Technically my answer was first (by two minutes), but I'm glad you got what you needed!

Comment: You're right, sorry. I didn't see the datestamp the other day and presumed the first answer on the list was the first chronologically.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if you are in a category archive, and then get the current category being displayed and the get the last post from that category. In your category archive page (archive.php, category.php, index.php, ... whatever you use):

```
   if( is_category() ) {

    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
        $args = array(
                     'posts_per_page' => 1,
                     'cat'            => $cat,
                     'orderby'        => 'date',
                     'order'          => 'DESC',
                     'post_not_in'    => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

       if ( $query->have_posts() ) {  
            while( $query->have_posts() ) {  
                $query->the_post();      
                 get_template_part( 'content', 'latest' );
            }
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
   }
```

Comment: That's great, @cybnet. It works perfectly for categories, and I guess I can apply the same principle to tag and search archive pages, using conditional statements or templates. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, you ca apply the same approach to tag, search, montly ... any archive-index page. Just use the correct conditionals.

Comment: Sorry, I see now that @unifiedac's answer was posted first, so I've changed my accepted answer.

Comment: Oh, yes. I've never seen it.